# Posting data with ESP8266 module?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, node.js

I have an ESP8266 module attached to an Arduino Uno that is connected to my local network. On the network, at address 192.168.1.13, I have a nodejs/express server running on port 3000. How would I go about posting an eight digit number from the Arduino to the webserver? In my current attempts the server console isn't receiving any data when using AT+CIPSEND while connected to it.

EDIT: My Code is as follows:

```
     #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const byte rxPin = 9; // Wire this to Tx Pin of ESP8266
const byte txPin = 10; // Wire this to Rx Pin of ESP8266

// We'll use a software serial interface to connect to ESP8266
SoftwareSerial ESP8266 (rxPin, txPin);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ESP8266.begin(9600); // Change this to the baudrate used by ESP8266
  delay(1000); // Let the module self-initialize
  Serial.println("Sending an AT command...");
  ESP8266.println("AT+CWMODE=1");
  delay(1000);
  ESP8266.println("AT+CWJAP=\"username\",\"pass\"");
  delay(10000);
  ESP8266.println("AT+CIPMODE=1");
  delay(1000);
  ESP8266.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"192.168.1.13\test\",3000");
  delay(1000);
  GetData();

}
void loop() {
 while (ESP8266.available()){
     String inData = ESP8266.readStringUntil('\n');
     Serial.println("Got reponse from ESP8266: " + inData);
  }
}
void GetData(){
  ESP8266.println("AT+CIPSEND=4");
  ESP8266.print("test");
}
```

and My output is this

```
  Sending an AT command...
Got reponse from ESP8266: AT+CWMODE=1


Got reponse from ESP8266: 

Got reponse from ESP8266: OK

Got reponse from ESP8266: AT+CWJAP="surveillancevan4","7073199495"


Got reponse from ESP8266: AT+CIPSEND=4


Got reponse from ESP8266: testI
```

EDIT 2: I modified my code to this

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const byte rxPin = 9; // Wire this to Tx Pin of ESP8266
const byte txPin = 10; // Wire this to Rx Pin of ESP8266
// We'll use a software serial interface to connect to ESP8266
SoftwareSerial ESP8266 (rxPin, txPin);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ESP8266.begin(9600); // Change this to the baudrate used by ESP8266
  ESP8266.println("AT");
  delay(1000);
  ESP8266.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"192.168.1.13\",3000");
  delay(20000);
  String request = "POST /test HTTP/1.0 \r\n";
  ESP8266.println("AT+CIPSEND=19");
  delay(5000);
  ESP8266.println(request);



}

void loop() {
 while (ESP8266.available()){
     String inData = ESP8266.readStringUntil('\n');
     Serial.println("Got reponse from ESP8266: " + inData);
  }
}
```

and now my output claims it posted successfully, but I'm still not seeing any data in my nodejs server. Here is the output:
Got reponse from ESP8266:

```
AT


Got reponse from ESP8266: 

Got reponse from ESP8266: OK

Got reponse from ESP8266: AT+CIPSTART="TCP","192.168.1.13",3000


Got reponse from ESP8266: CONNECT

Got reponse from ESP8266: 

Got reponse from ESP8266: O 



Got reponse from ESP8266: busy sytes

Got reponse from ESP8266: 

Got reponse from ESP8266: SEND OK
```

I can confirm that it is connecting to my web app because when I run the code on the module without the server running it returns an error.

Comment: Avoid "\" in URL, these are not standard separators, in addition these are escape characters in C and C++ strings. Your `"192.168.1.13\test\"` should probably be replaced with `"192.168.1.13/test\"`.

Comment: I think it would help us (and yourself too) if you traced the response of all AT commands sent to the ESP8266, so that we could check that all of them succeed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ESP8266.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"192.168.1.13\test\",3000");
```

That line is going to fail miserably for a number of reasons:

1. You need to provide an IP address or domain name - NOT a URL
2. Even if you could provide a URL this bit `192.168.1.13\test` would end up, after C escaping, as `92.168.1.13        est` since `\t` is a TAB character.

And then on top of all that I assume you are connecting to a HTTP server, yet you aren't sending a HTTP request, you are just sending the word "test", which the HTTP server has no hope of ever understanding.

You need to formulate and send a proper HTTP request and send it to the server. I suggest you go and look at a few tutorials and maybe look up how HTTP Servers actually operate and what the protocol looks like.